# Can I specify a function in python this way or will my results be corrupted

Tags: python, r

I am trying to bring something from an R package by Lotze & Loecher into python as all of the rest of the project is.

Here is the python code:

```
def dbeta(x,shape1,shape2):
    from scipy.stats import beta
    result=beta.pdf(x=x,a=shape1,b=shape2,loc=0,scale=1)
    return result

def pbeta(q,shape1,shape2):
    from scipy.stats import beta
    result=beta.cdf(x=q,a=shape1,b=shape2,loc=0,scale=1)
    return result


def combinations(array, tuple_length, prev_array=[]):
    if len(prev_array) == tuple_length:
        return [prev_array]
    combs = []
    for f, val in enumerate(array):
        prev_array_extended = prev_array.copy()
        prev_array_extended.append(val)
        combs += combinations(array[f+1:], tuple_length, prev_array_extended)
    return combs
```

After defining these functions here I have the problem with too many iterations in the function I think:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
def best_binominal_bandit(x, n, alpha=1, beta=1):
    ans = []
    # x = vector of number of successes
    # n = vector of number of tries
    k = len(x)
    l = list(range(0,k))
    b = combinations(l, k-1)
    for i in l:
        indx = b[i]
        def f(z):
            r = dbeta(z, x[i] + alpha, n[i] - x[i] + beta)
            for j in indx:
                r = r*pbeta(z, x[j] + alpha, n[j] - x[j] + beta)
            return r
        
        a = quad(f, 0, 1)[0]
        ans.append(a)
        
    return ans
```

So when calling

```
x = [10,20,30,50]
n = [100,102,120,130]
best_binominal_bandit(x, n)
```

I do not receive similar results as they do in their specification. I have the feeling that there are just more iterations in the `f` function. After all, the bottom line should add up to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution. I will post it here and then close the question. Seems like I misread something and made an easy mistake (that kept vexing me however).

The combination function is not necessary for what I intended, rather the ith element of the list simply needs to be excluded.

```
def dbeta(x,shape1,shape2):
    from scipy.stats import beta
    result=beta.pdf(x=x,a=shape1,b=shape2,loc=0,scale=1)
    return result

def pbeta(q,shape1,shape2):
    from scipy.stats import beta
    result=beta.cdf(x=q,a=shape1,b=shape2,loc=0,scale=1)
    return result
```

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
def best_binominal_bandit(x, n, alpha=1, beta=1):
    ans = []
    k = len(x)
    l = list(range(0,k))
    for i in l:
        excluded_index = i
        indx = l[:excluded_index] + l[excluded_index+1:]
        def f(z):
            r = dbeta(z, x[i] + alpha, n[i] - x[i] + beta)
            print(z)
            for j in indx:
                r = r*pbeta(z, x[j] + alpha, n[j] - x[j] + beta)
            return r  
        a = quad(f, 0, 1)[0]
        ans.append(a)
        
    return ans
```

All in all this seems to work for a python translation of: p. 648 in
Scott, S. L. (2010). A modern Bayesian look at the multi-armed bandit. Applied Stochastic Models in Business and Industry, 26(6), 639–658. doi:10.1002/asmb.874